# Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, canvas, jquery-plugins, photo-upload

I'm experiencing some issues related to Jquery photo upload (https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) plugin and its preview upload functionality. I'm able to pick up the file but once it tries to set the selected image for preview in a table, it shows the following error:

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/server/controller/edit/1/1/laf02.jpg"
```

In order to preview the image, I use the following JS code:

```
var canvas = $('#preview' + i)[0];
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img = new Image();
img.src = files[i].name;
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
```

Where files is a file array containing all selected files and canvas contains a canvas element.

Why does it show the error? I don't think draw Image sends a request to server. The controller sending the jsp page has produces in @RequestMapping.

I hope you can help me guys.

Comment: Please show us how Spring handles the `/server/controller/edit/1/1/laf02.jpg` request.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I don't have a controller handling such request, I mean I don't think that's necessary since this is kind of a pre-upload step, where the user can preview the selected image. I believe there's no need to implement a controller, since if that were the case I would already be uploading the image.

Comment: What _serves_ the response to the request to the URL in my previous comment?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know why that request is generated. The JS code in my question is performing the request but I don't know why. That code is executed right after user has selected the images to upload, so that I can display a preview of his selections. In order to achieve that, I'm using a canvas element to draw on (as you can see in the code). However, it generates the request that fails and since I don't understand why, I don't have a controller to send a response.

Comment: I don't know how to help you. If this is a Spring issue, you have to show us what you are doing in Spring. Open your browser's network console and check the traffic going to a from your server.